# python unicode error : why do I keep getting this caracters although I used encode(utf-8)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, unicode, utf-8, pycharm

```
for p in articles2:
    url = p.find('a')['href']
    title = p.find('h3').get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
    print(title)
```

OUTPUT:

```
c3\xa9gie de d\xc3\xa9fense active et pr\xc3\xa9ventive\xc2\xbb'

b'Zoom sur la course effr\xc3\xa9n\xc3\xa9e pour trouver un vaccin'

b'On vous le dit'

b'\xc3\x89dition du jour (PDF)'

b'Son port est d\xc3\xa9sormais obligatoire : Le prix du masque plafonn\xc3\xa9'

b'Baisse de 20% des prix des produits agricoles' .....
```

Comment: Kindly share sample input data and expected output in copy pastable format

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? The output is UTF-8-encoded, and a `bytes` object. If you want to output strings. don't encode.

Comment: Those are utf-8 encoded byte strings which is the normal output of `.encode('utf-8')`. If I do `b'Zoom sur la course effr\xc3\xa9n\xc3\xa9e pour trouver un vaccin'.decode('utf-8')` I get `'Zoom sur la course effrénée pour trouver un vaccin'`. Encdoing to byte string is good for saving to a file or sending to the network but its not good for human viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different encoding, it seems this characters are Latin-1.

You can find more encodings [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` and `join`  to translate the characters.

i.e  `"Zoom sur la course effr\xc3\xa9n\xc3\xa9e pour trouver un vaccin"`
 will be `'Zoom sur la course effrÃ©nÃ©e pour trouver un vaccin'` after `join` and `split()`

Then `encode` it to `ascii` ignoring errors `'ignore'` and `decode` it to `utf-8` this is in order to remove the special characters such as `Ã©`

Should look like:

`"".join(the_text_to_clean.strip()).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8")`

**How it applies in your code**

```
for p in articles2:
   url = p.find('a')['href']
   title = p.find('h3').get_text()
   title = "".join(title.strip()).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8") #clean title
   print(title)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this answers the question.