# Scraping special characters with SCRAPY

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was scraping a page in the Danish Language. I am having trouble with the output. The output contains many special characters like `(Ã¥, Ã, Ã¥, Ã¦)` and it's not like the one on the page.

How can I scrape the text just like on the page?

Example link: https://novaindex.com/dk/leverandoerer/mode-og-tekstiler/arbejdstoej

```
import scrapy
    
class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main'

    start_urls = ['https://novaindex.com/dk/leverandoerer/mode-og-tekstiler/arbejdstoej']

    def parse(self, response):

        details = response.xpath('//a[@class="companyresult "]')

        for each in details:
            name = each.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="name"]/text())').get()
            street = each.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="street"]/text())').get()
            city = each.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="city"]/text())').get()
            phone = each.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="phone"]/text())').get()

            yield {
                "Name": name,
                "Street Address": street,
                "City Address": city,
                "Phone": phone,
            }
```

Comment: Which python version do you use?
I strongly suggest you to switch to python3 which will solve most of your problems with unicode symbols.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7

Comment: I tried it with selenium with utf-8 and it's didn't' work but when I removed utf-8 encoding, the output was same as the website. So, do you know how can I ignore utf-8 encoding with scrapy?

Comment: 3.7 is nice. And one more question: what's your output?


I mean where do you see broken symbols? do you scrape to file/to screen/to database?

Comment: In general scrapy gets the page content correctly in 99.99999999% of time. The problem in your case is to show this content correctly. I believe if you'll add some print(name) statements inside of your code you'll see correct letters.

Comment: I think the issue is with the exporting data to CSV file. I exported the data to JSON and it worked fine.

Comment: hah... it's quite known problem indeed. 
Which app do you use to open csv file?
You should mention Utf encoding there to open file correctly. I know Excel has some troubles with it. Unfortunately I can't guide you in this because I don't use anything except of linux for years already.

Comment: Yes, I used excel to open the file. Anyways, thanks a lot. I converted the JSON file to Excel and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Danish codec is `cp865` check all available codecs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

**NB:** Use `ascii` only if your scraping english website.

```
def string_cleaner(rouge_text):
    return ("".join(rouge_text.strip()).encode('cp865', 'ignore').decode("cp865"))
```

Use `ignore` to ignore errors

**Usage**

```
 yield {
                "Name": string_cleaner(name),
                ...
            }
```

*More explanation on what the code does check my code breakdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975855/python-unicode-error-why-do-i-keep-getting-this-caracters-although-i-used-enco/62007774#62007774)*

Comment: This method completely skips the letters. 
NORDJYSK DØGNGALVANISERING AKTIESELSKAB
to
NORDJYSK DGNGALVANISERING AKTIESELSKAB

it has skipped the following letter Ø

Comment: use the danish code `cp865` instead of `ascii` which is english. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could add `.encode('utf8')` after `get()` or `getall()`

Scrapy extracts data as unicode strings, this may help you understand abit about unicode and UTF-8.

[What is a unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808657/what-is-a-unicode-string/21809081)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I tried it with selenium with utf-8 and it's didn't' work but when I removed utf-8 encoding, the output was same as the website. So, do you know how can I ignore utf-8 encoding with scrapy?